# Locating the positions of an array within another array

Tags: c#, arrays, indexof

I am looking for all positions of an array within another array.
In the examples on the next page, values are strings but I need to work with arrays:
[Array.IndexOf Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-7.0)

Here are my examples:

```
Array.IndexOf(new byte[12] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 13}, new byte[2] {13, 10}, 0)
```

Returned -1. Desired 4

```
Array.IndexOf(new byte[12] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 13}, new byte[2] {13, 10}, 5)
```

Returned -1. Desired 10

Thanks